# How to dynamically change an app certificate when certificate gets expired? I don't want my customers to download a latest app from playstore

Tags: android, ssl-certificate

I have an application that has 1000's of user. My ssl certificates gets expired after 2 years. Last time I pushed an update to playstore with new ssl certificate. Now I want a permanent solution for this and I don't want my customers to download latest app. How can I dynamically add new certificate to existing app?